# Displaying repositories from more than one user or organization on a GitHub Page

Tags: github, github-api, github-pages

I'm currently creating my own GitHub page (http://ihanken.github.io) and I would like to present both my personal open source repositories and the open source repositories from an organization I am a part of.

Below is the code I use to pull the repositories to display my open source projects on the "Open Source" page, which is located at http://ihanken.github.io/open-source

```
{% assign sorted_repos = (site.github.public_repositories | sort: 'stargazers_count') | reverse | where: "fork", "false" %}
```

With site.github.public_repositories, I can only pull either the repositories from the github account my page is associated with, or I can specify the organization's account, but I can't seem to do both at once. Does anyone have some insight on this issue?

Comment: Can you show how to specify the organization's account? is that if you build the jekyll website in the organization's repo?

Comment: @StephenG This website is being built in my personal repo, but in my config.yml file, I can change `repository: ihanken/contributions` to `repository: froghat` to pull all public froghat repos instead, but then I lose my own. I haven't figured out how to add both.